# Applications cannot start or close

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, usb-c, dongle

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and just came across a very strange issue: I was developing an asynchronous application in PyCharm while I noticed that the application that I was debugging did not terminate. `kill -9` didn't do anything. I closed PyCharm, but nothing happened.

I opened Firefox, but it told me that I should first close Firefox. So, I identified all running Firefox PIDs and `kill -9` them. But still: "Please close Firefox first".

I closed every application and re-opened it. Except for the file manager and the terminal, every application failed to appear. PyCharm still couldn't be closed. Shutdown also didn't do anything. So, I had to press the on-off button of the laptop.

After restart, the network interface (WIFI card) wasn't found. Then, I unplugged my DELL DA200 USB-C dongle, restart the machine and everything was fine again.

This was not the first time this happened. Is there some explanation of this strange behavior? It was probably the fault of the USB-C dongle, but how could it destroy the system like this?